# How to bind to a function dynamically, similar to live

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I am using a 3rd party utility tool and I can't change the code in that cool. The tool does nothing else but

```
$(this).live('click', function(){

 this.trigger('custom:callback');

});
```

The way I use it is

```
$('a').bind('custom:callback', function(){
  alert('callback is being invoked');
});
```

Above code works fine. However if I dynamically create an 'a' element then I HAVE to run

```
$('a').bind('custom:callback', function(){
  alert('callback is being invoked');
});
```

otherwise the callback by the third party tool does not work.

Is there a way to setup the binding dynamically so that if I dynamically create an 'a' element then I don't need to run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with custom events as well, for example:

```
$('a').live('custom:callback', function(){
  alert('callback is being invoked');
});
```

This should eliminate the need to bind to each as it appears, though if you *have* to do that, it's what [the `.livequery()` plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) is still good at...it would look like this:

```
$('a').livequery(function() {
  $(this).bind('custom:callback', function() {
    alert('callback is being invoked');
  });
});
```